# meteor and reactJS - how to make child components reactive?

Tags: meteor, reactjs, reactive-programming

I have a child component that depends on another widget to set what data it should subscribe to. So effectively a dynamic subscription.

`getMeteorData() {
    var topicName = this.context.topicName;
    var handle = Meteor.subscribe('RebotTopicDetail', {name: topicName});
    ...`

If topicName changes I want to re-subscribe to new data.

What is the best way to do this?

The `topicName` is being set by another component, and I am using context to pass it between objects.
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html
I can see the `context.topicName` is changing as I am displaying it.
But it's not triggering the reactive calculation inside meteor data to rerun.

Is there a way to declare a Deps on a variable within getMeteorData?
My understanding was that was a reactive block so changes would cause the getMeteorData block to re-run.

https://react-in-meteor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/meteor-data/

I also tried passing the `topicName` in via `props`, but that also doesn't trigger a reactive update.

for others coming here, related threads

- https://github.com/meteor/react-packages/issues/19
- https://github.com/meteor/react-packages/issues/66
- https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2517

Answer (score 0):

edit: props seems to be reactive

```

```
  getMeteorData() {
    var topicName = this.props.topicName;
    var handle = Meteor.subscribe('RebotTopicDetail', {name: topicName});


/// and in the container passing in a prop
<TriggerList topicName={this.state.topicName} />
```

```

works. not sure if using state of the container item had something to do with it.